# Is there a torsion element in the homology cylinder group?

Tags: 3-manifolds

The homology cylinder group is the monoid of homology cylinders modulo homology cobordism. I wonder whether there is any known finite order element in this group.

Comment: Could you explain which dimension(s) you're interested in? Since there's a 3-manifold tag, presumably the cylinders or their boundaries have dimension 3? 

Comment: @Agol: I think he is referring to 3-dimensional cylinders with surface boundary.

Comment: @Agol: yes, Conant is right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certainly there is a lot of $2$-torsion. One easy way to construct such an example is to look at the embedding of the string link cobordism group on $n$ strands into the homology cobordism group of genus $n$. (Levine explains this embedding in his paper "Homology cylinders: an enlargment of the mapping class group." See Theorem 4 of that paper.) The string link group has lots of $2$-torsion. For example just tie an amphicheiral knot (which is not slice) into one of the strands. In fact the knot concordance group has infinitely many $\mathbb Z_2$ summands which inject into the homology cylinder group.

Comment: Thank you! You helps me a lot. Is there any other example, for surfaces with boundary ?

Comment: @HJ: this construction is for surfaces with one boundary component. I am sure there are other examples too. This paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.5580 shows there are infinitely many $\mathbb Z_2$ invariants, which should be realizable by actual homology cylinders, though I don't know off the top of my head.

Comment: @Conant: Would there be more example for more boundary componant?

Comment: @HJ: Sure. The map from string links to homology cobordisms extends to arbitrary numbers of components. Also, a string link is a homology cobordism of a planar surface so you get lots of direct examples that way. 